# Heap corruption detection tool for C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory

Is there any tool to help me detect heap corruption in C++? I can't provide source code because it's a big project. I can use any tool that works with Visual Studio or with xcode. The tool should work fine with multithreading. The problem is not very common, it appears after a long time and only in very special cases(they were not detected precisely!).

Thank you!

EDIT:

Thanks you all for your answers! I will test the tools and I will accept one answer after the tests.

Comment: Under which conditions do you want to detect this heap corruption? Can you run the process under a debugger? Debug or release build? Developer or production machine?

Comment: I can run the process in debug mode, I have the source code, I can run it on PC/MAC/iPhone/iPad(99% of the code, some small initialization part is different and some OS specific parts, but the problem is in all builds, so it must be from common parts)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is **the** defacto tool for doing memory instrumentation for native code. It, however, does not run on Windows (OS X is fine).

There are a few commercial tools which do run on Windows, and while they feature a GUI, are in my opinion inferior to Valgrind.

Comment: Note that only recent Valgrind versions support OSX.

Comment: Note: Valgrind is the core tool, and comes with several plugins. Plugins usually feature a GUI to make sense of the verbose output file generated.

Answer (score 6):

The debugging tools for Windows include [gflags and page heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff549561%28VS.85%29.aspx) which help detecting heap corruptions.

Answer (score 3):

On Mac OS X (which I presume is what you mean when you say Xcode), you have a whole bunch of memory debugging tools already, e.g. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-MallocOptions/index.html which lets you turn on heap checking via environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows use [Application Verifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms220948%28VS.90%29.aspx)