# How to detect heap corruption errors under MinGW?

Tags: debugging, mingw, heap-memory

How to debug mingw built binaries to detect heap errors? I see there are several questions on the topic, but they are general and it's hard to find the tool that would work well with MinGW. I spent much time on finding the solution, I hope the combined topic will be helpful.

Such a tool becomes necessary when for example someone reports a bug in your library while running it under Visual Studio debugger, which stops with a "Heap Error".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a tool provided by Microsoft called [Application Verifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms220948(v=vs.90).aspx). It is a gui tool that changes system settings to run selected applications in a controlled environment. This makes it possible to **crash your program if it causes detectable memory errors**. This is a controlled crash that can be debugged.

Fortunately it is obtainable from Microsoft as [a separate download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20028). Another way to get it is to have Windows SDK installed with checked *Application Verifier* checkbox. SDK offers also an option *Application Verifier redistributable*.

After you configure Application Verifier to have an eye for your app, you need to debug it. Debugging under MinGW is a more common subject, already explained on stackoverflow. [[mingw] [debugging]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mingw+debugging) query on stackoverflow gives interesting articles. One of them is [How do I use the MinGW gdb debugger to debug a C++ program in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4671900/772981). Gdb is the one I used.

The general questions [How to debug heap corruption errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1010106/772981) and [Heap corruption detection tool for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4689274/772981) were helpful to find this tool, but I wasn't sure if it is compatible with MinGW. It is.

Comment: As at 2021-07-08, the separate download link is dead